# Xcode - Terminating due to uncaught exception for iphone app

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode3.2

When I try to cick on cell in my table view rather than take me to the next view I get a "Terminating due to uncaught exception" error.

Here is the code from the debugger:

```
010-03-27 12:52:48.805 MultiDetailView[335:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'
2010-03-27 12:52:48.809 MultiDetailView[335:207] Stack: (
    40849995,
    2476418313,
    40849435,
    40849274,
    592937,
    50711,
    5698680,
    5701555,
    5697083,
    5705902,
    11163,
    3128431,
    3089967,
    191242,
    40390524,
    40386632,
    49203357,
    49203554,
    2788833,
    9060,
    8914
)
```

Any ideas on what I should do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your array:

> reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'

In other words, you're trying to access an object at index 1 (i.e. the second object in the array), while the array contains less than two objects.

Comment: Thanks very much especially for taking the time to explain :)

Comment: You're welcome, others did and do the same for me. That's how we advance steadily to deeper levels of being stymied ;)